# fapiPrivate_post_leverage on mexc exchange for Futures

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, ccxt

Description
the error is :
`AttributeError: 'mexc' object has no attribute 'fapiPrivate_post_leverage'` 
i made script in python for
Futures mexc with a leverage of 100 x the purchase order and the termination of the deal Market taking profits on a profit of 0.01% as an example
In the event that I entered number 1 in the terminal script, I will execute a purchase order or wait to take profits, or enter number 3 to end the transaction with a market order

the error is :
AttributeError: 'mexc' object has no attribute 'fapiPrivate_post_leverage

and if you have anything to edit or improve script im need help

my python code :

```
import ccxt

api_key = 'api_key'
secret = 'secret'
leverage = 100
symbol = 'BTC/USDT'  # Bitcoin trading pair
take_profit_percentage = 0.01  # 0.01% profit

exchange = ccxt.mexc({  # Assuming exchange is Binance
    'apiKey': api_key,
    'secret': secret,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'options': {
        'defaultType': 'future'
    }
})

def create_long_order():
    data = exchange.fapiPrivate_post_leverage({
        'symbol': symbol.replace('/', ''),
        'leverage': leverage
    })

    market_price = exchange.fetch_ticker(symbol)['last']
    balance_usdt = exchange.fetch_balance()['total']['USDT']  # Fetch your USDT balance
    amount_btc = balance_usdt / market_price  # Use your total USDT to buy BTC
    order = exchange.create_market_buy_order(symbol, amount_btc)
    print('Buy order created at market price:', market_price)
    return order

def close_order_at_market():
    balance = exchange.fetch_balance()['total']['BTC']
    order = exchange.create_market_sell_order(symbol, balance)
    print('Order closed at market price')
    return order

while True:
    action = input("Enter 1 to execute a buy order, 3 to close the order at market price: ")
    if action == '1':
        order = create_long_order()
        while True:
            order_info = exchange.fetch_order(order['id'], symbol)
            if order_info['status'] == 'closed':
                print('Order closed with a profit of 0.01%')
                break
            elif float(exchange.fetch_ticker(symbol)['last']) >= float(order['info']['price']) * (1 + take_profit_percentage):  # Fetch the latest price
                close_order = close_order_at_market()
                break
    elif action == '3':
        close_order = close_order_at_market()
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ccxt group or ask mexc cs?

I suspect it's because mexc has disabled their futures API since last year, I'm not sure if they have re-enabled it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I changed from fapiPrivate_post_leverage to fapiPrivatePostLeverage and it's work